# How to group by with rollup?

Tags: 7, database

How to get booking records from booking table? How to get `GROUP BY` function `WITH ROLLUP`?

Here is my SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM booking 
GROUP BY startBooking WITH ROLLUP;
```

How to convert above query in Drupal 7?

```
     $queryPrice = db_select('booking', 'b');
     $queryPrice->fields('b');  
     $queryPrice->groupBy('b.startBooking');       
     $resultPrice = $queryPrice->execute();
```

How to roll up use in above query in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `GROUP` modifier right to the end of the string:

```
$queryPrice->groupBy('b.startBooking WITH ROLLUP');
```

With the rest of your query Drupal produces:

```
SELECT  b.*
FROM 
{booking} b
GROUP BY b.startBooking WITH ROLLUP
```